# Public access to Mashup Workspace + Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to make a mashup public. This mashup uses Orion Context Broker to draw some PoI in a map. I've looked at documentation on [github](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-source-operator/blob/master/doc/userguide.md) and tried changing port to 10026 and disabling the use of credentials, but I don't get any PoIs this way.

The NGSI Source Operator settings are:

- NGSI server URL: `http://orion.lab.fiware.org:10026/`
- NGSI proxy URL: `https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org`
- Use the FIWARE credentials of the user : disabled

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [NGSI source operator documentation](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-source-operator/blob/3.0.3/doc/userguide.md) (version 3.0.3), using the `10026` port was a hack for supporting public workspaces. That hack doesn't work anymore.

Version 3.0.4 of the NGSI Source operator adds support for using the credentials of the workspace owner instead of using the credentials of the logged user (through a new preference: `Use the FIWARE credentials of the workspace owner`). This can be used for creating a workspace and make it public.